# Order of constructor/destructor calls in c++

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a `PhoneBook` class and a `Contact` class. My PhoneBook constructor should instantiate an array of 8 contacts. It actually works but when i print the constructors/destructors calls, I dont understand the output.

Here is my main followed by the classes with their respective constructors/destructors:

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    PhoneBook   phonebook;

    //..

    return (0);
}
```

```cpp
class Contact
{
    public:
        Contact();                  // construct a Contact
        ~Contact();                 // destruct a Contact
        void    init(void);         // init a Contact
        void    preview(int) const; // preview a Contact
        void    print(int) const;   // print a Contact
        void    setIndex(int);      // set index

    private:
        std::string _first_name;
        std::string _last_name;
        std::string _nickname;
        std::string _phone_number;
        std::string _darkest_secret;
        int         _index;
        std::string _printLen(std::string str) const;
        std::string _getInput(std::string str) const;
};

Contact::Contact()
{
    std::cout << "Contact created" << std::endl << std::flush;
}

Contact::~Contact()
{
    std::cout << "Contact destroyed" << std::endl << std::flush;
}
```

```cpp
class PhoneBook
{
    public:
        PhoneBook(); // construct a PhoneBook
        ~PhoneBook(); // destroy a PhoneBook
        std::string welcome(void) const;
        void        addEntry(void);     // add a new contact
        void        previewContacts(void) const;
        void        searchEntry(void) const;

    private:
        Contact _contacts[8];   // pointer to the elements
        int     _size;          // number of contacts
};

PhoneBook::PhoneBook(): _size(0)
{
    std::cout << "PhoneBook created" << std::endl << std::flush;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        _contacts[i] = Contact();
}

PhoneBook::~PhoneBook()
{
    std::cout << "PhoneBook destroyed" << std::endl << std::flush;
}
```

Output I got:

```
Contact created
Contact created
Contact created
Contact created
Contact created
Contact created
Contact created
Contact created
PhoneBook created
Contact created
Contact destroyed
Contact created
Contact destroyed
Contact created
Contact destroyed
Contact created
Contact destroyed
Contact created
Contact destroyed
Contact created
Contact destroyed
Contact created
Contact destroyed
Contact created
Contact destroyed
```

Output I expected:

```
PhoneBook created
Contact created
Contact created
Contact created
Contact created
Contact created
Contact created
Contact created
Contact created
Contact destroyed
Contact destroyed
Contact destroyed
Contact destroyed
Contact destroyed
Contact destroyed
Contact destroyed
Contact destroyed
PhoneBook destroyed
```

I noted that if I declared my _contacts object as `Contact *_contacts`in my `PhoneBook` class, and I allocated it with `new` in my PhoneBook constructor, and deleted it with `delete[]` in my destructor, everything goes well, the expected output is printed.
Can someone please explain ?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) _contacts[i] = Contact();` is unneeded/useless, `Contact contacts[8];` already does the job.

Comment: I suspect you left out the assignment loop in the dynamic case.

Comment: [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) already flushes, no need to repeat that.

Comment: @Mat Are you certain about this ? I saw this written in several different places/codes ?

Comment: https://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.manip <- C++ standard draft if you don't trust cppreference  (which you should above pretty much anything else on the net)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_contacts` gets initialized before you ever enter the body of the constructor.

```
PhoneBook::PhoneBook(): _size(0)
{
    std::cout << "PhoneBook created" << std::endl << std::flush;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        _contacts[i] = Contact();
}
```

Is actually

```
PhoneBook::PhoneBook(): _contacts{}, _size(0)
{
    std::cout << "PhoneBook created" << std::endl << std::flush;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        _contacts[i] = Contact();
}
```

and it is that `_contacts{}` that causes the first eight constructor calls you see.  The rest is from

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    _contacts[i] = Contact();
```

and you see a construction and destruction for each `Contact()` temporary object you create in the for loop.

Comment: The order of construction of members is in the order they are declared.   Since the member of `PhoneBook` are specified in the order `_contacts` then `size`, `_contacts` is initialised before `size`.   Your initialiser list `_size(0), _contacts{}` does not cause `_size` to be initialised first.

Comment: @Peter I never claimed it did, I just said it was responsible for the first eight `Contact` constructor calls.  I have adjusted the example code to reflect the actual order of the member initialization.

Comment: @BobDeTunis Include the `this` pointer in your log messages so that you can see *WHICH* objects are being created/destroyed. And don't forget to log the copy/move constructors too, eg: `Contact::Contact() { std::cout << "Contact created " << (void*)this << std::endl; } Contact::Contact(const Contact &c) { std::cout << "Contact copied " << (void*)this << " from " << (void*)&c << std::endl; } Contact::Contact(Contact &&c) { std::cout << "Contact moved " << (void*)this << " from " << (void*)&c << std::endl; } Contact::~Contact() { std::cout << "Contact destroyed " << (void*)this << std::endl; }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for this useful tip. I implemented it in my code

Comment: @NathanOliver   I realise you didn't claim that.  But the question and your answer are about order of initialisation, and I suggest it's better to be as explicit as possible about the order of things rather than leaving some parts open to incorrect interpretation.